Use enum fields to define higher level aggregate
In the project I am working on, it's a common pattern to have a function like MachineType.get_external to group the fields:
from enum import IntEnum

class MachineType(IntEnum):
    Cloud = 1
    OnPrem = 2
    Saas = 3

    @classmethod
    def get_external(cls):
        return [
            MachineType.Cloud,
            MachineType.Saas
        ]

I don't like it and would rather prefer having something more efficient, like:
class MachineAggregateType:
    EXTERNAL = [MachineType.Cloud, MachineType.Saas]

i.e. less function calls and less list constructions. (It is used in event processing service, doing 1M events/min, and there are many classes like this which are used for every given event.)
Is there a way to have such grouping in the original class as a class field? In my opinion it's better for maintainability and structure than another class.

Just realized that adding any non int class field to MachineType is bad decision since  MachineType is IntEnum. Closing this question

If the enums are few in number (and therefore easy to manually adjust when necessary), you can use a Constant:
class Constant:  # use Constant(object) if in Python 2
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __get__(self, *args):
        return self.value
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.value)

and in use:
class MachineType(IntEnum):
    Cloud = 1
    OnPrem = 2
    Saas = 3
    EXTERNAL = Constant((MachineType.Cloud, MachineType.Saas))

Note: I changed it from a (mutable) list to an (immutable) tuple to guard against accidental modification.
